# how i send javascript varible to php file and save it in database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have one variable in javascript file and I want to send this variable into database using ajax,

```
var name = "test";
$.ajax({url: 'insert.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: name,
    success:function(response){
            alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: That code would work just fine, and sends your one variable to the serverside, but you have to handle it on the serverside and write the code that inserts it into the database, nothing happens without you telling it to happen.

Comment: You could add echo $_POST['name']; to insert.php and change your callback to say alert(response); to test if the variable was sent. If it is working you should get "test" as an alert message.

Comment: What server side code do you have?

Comment: $myVar = $POST['name'] ;
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','nxtlg6nk_9tv','DN+#nKN1o~Bx') or die (mysql_error);

$db=mysql_select_db('nxtlg6nk_9tv', $conn) or die (mysql_error);


    $qry = mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO laasri_videos (title) VALUES ($myVar)');

Answer (score 6):

The `data` must be key value pairs, use:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'insert.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {name: name}, // or data: "name="+name,
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

And the php side:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: Using an object for data is a good idea, but for sending just one value, there's nothing really wrong with not using an object?

Comment: The point being, the OP's code works just fine, it sends the string, and that string can be retrieved from `$_POST`, even if it's not in the form of an associative array like `$_POST` would be if you'd use key/value pairs.

Comment: how i check my data goes to insert.php file

Comment: @xdazz i have use console.log(response); then my ajax not responed

Comment: @adeneo I tested, the key will not even be set if you just do `data: name`, the `$_POST` will be empty.

Comment: @ManojSharma did you check it in console?

Comment: @xdazz  so how i set the key

Comment: @ManojSharma That's in my answer.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, as jQuery accepts strings, arrays, objects and just about anything as data, and it's all converted to strings internally anyway, as that's the only thing that can be sent this way, so just sending a string should work just as well, and $_POST shouldn't be empty. Again, I think it's a good idea to use an object like you're doing, I just for the life of me can't see how this answers the question of how to get the data into a database, as the ajax call in the question should work fine.

Comment: @adeneo Have you tried it yourself or checked the document? If you just pass an string, at least you should have `data: name+'='`, then `"test"` will be a key in `$_POST`, otherwise `$_POST` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using something like:

```
    var name = "test";

    $.ajax({
        url : 'insert.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {'name' : name},
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    }).done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  }).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  }).always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

and then in php check for `$_POST['name'];`

Comment: yes  i have do it but it is not working

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST)) 
 {   $etitle = $_GET['name'];
   
    $qry = mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO laasri_videos (title) VALUES ($etitle)');
 }   i have use this code in insert.php but its not working

Comment: Do you have the right path for insert.php ? Try echoing something in insert.php to check if you have the right path.

Comment: how i check that my path in right

Comment: as I said, go to your insert.php file on your server and at the top of the file right after your <?php tag write echo "test"; then activate the ajax call and see if you get the alert on the success function.

Comment: @ManojSharma  your ajax type is POST and you use GET to receive value which is wrong . use `$etitle = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: yes i have check but how i check the ajax call

Comment: Your ajax call must be activated by a click or a submit or something along those lines, if you get the alert in the success function it means your variables are being sent to your insert.php and you can handle your database insert from there. If you are not getting the alert to fire then the ajax call is not successful. Also use something like die(); or exit(); in your php file.

Comment: and  how i check that my varibale goes to insert.php file

Comment: write echo $_POST['name]; die(); and then in your ajax write alert(response);

Comment: @OvidiuIacomi  my alert(response); is not alert anything,

Comment: @ManojSharma check my edit to debug your ajax call.

Comment: @OvidiuIacomi  i have check it first show blank alert then succuss and then complete

Comment: Please edit your question with all your code, js, php and html so that I can try to better answer your question. The ajax call is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can post more values with the { and }

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'insert.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
        name: name,
        variable2: variable2
    },
    success : function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

And in PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$variable2 = $_POST['variable2'];
```

And then you can do whatever you want with the variables.

Comment: you have to put `,` after `name: name`

Comment: Ouch, you're right. Thanks. Too much hurry :)

Comment: i have use it but data is not showing

Comment: The data will be sent to your PHP script, and you can access then with $name and $variable. You can do echo $name; echo $variable; and then it will be sent back to the browser, and shows in your alert.

The script above will only 'collect' the data sent to the script. You still have to process it to save it to datawith with mysql_query() etc.

Comment: @KoalaBear yes i want to save it in my database but i do not able to get the $name variable in insert.php file.

Comment: This really is everything. It will work. You have 4 of the exact same answers. There must be something else which is the problem. Or edit your question with the exact same code you are using right now. HTML + JS + PHP.

Comment: // js here 
var name = "manoj";
         $$.ajax({
        url: 'http://nextalgorithm.com/9tv/admincp/templates/default/insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
         
         Etitile: name
        },
        success:function(response){
          alert(response);
          }
          
  //php here
  
  echo $myVar = $GET['name'] ;

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','nxtlg6nk_9tv','DN+#nKN1o~Bx') or die (mysql_error);

$db=mysql_select_db('nxtlg6nk_9tv', $conn) or die (mysql_error);


    $qry = mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO laasri_videos (title) VALUES ($myVar)');

Comment: The error is in your PHP. Look at our examples. Use $_POST['name']; Not $GET (which is also wrong) or $_GET. Because you specify "type: 'POST'"

Comment: Always use $_GET or $_POST (not $GET or $POST, will not work)

Comment: @KoalaBear  i have use   $_GET or $_POST  in my php file but it not save the value in database and not showing any variable value

Comment: @krishna  can there is anyother way to insert the value in database

Comment: @ManojSharma I guess it's beter to edit your original question with the EXACT code you are using. We're all lost because you pasted pieces with wrong code, and when I say it is wrong, you're saying you're doing it right. Show us :)

Comment: //this is js
   var name = "test";
$.ajax({
  url: 'insert.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: name,
  
  success:function(response){
    }
         });

// this in insert.php

 conn.php (For database connection)
    if(isset($_REQUEST))
 
 {
   $etitle = $_POST['name'];
   
   
    $qry = mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO table(title) VALUES ($etitle)');
 }

Comment: have you written code for connecting to DB ?

Comment: @ManojSharma The problem is the mysql_query part. You are using single quotes, but also 'inline' PHP variables. Do it like this:
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table(title) VALUES ("' . mysql_real_escape_string($etitle) . '")');

Comment: Great! You're welcome. Next time update the original question, because the comments are very hard to read.

Comment: @KoalaBear ok sir, my query is working perfect but i do not get any value. please help

Comment: @ManojSharma POST COMPLETE CODE! And not here in the comments.

Comment: //js here

 
   var name = "test";

$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost/test/ajax/db/insert.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : name, // your javascript variable
    success : function(data) {

       alert(data);
    }
});
   //php here

echo   $etitle = $_POST['name'];

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error);

$db=mysql_select_db('test', $conn) or die (mysql_error);


  
 
  mysql_query('INSERT INTO user(user_name) VALUES ("' . mysql_real_escape_string($etitle) . '")');

Comment: Please... Not in the comments! And this is not the full code of HTML + JS + PHP. Go up this page, and Edit the original question.

Comment: var name = "test";

$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost/test/ajax/db/insert.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : name, // your javascript variable
    success : function(data) {

       alert(data);
    }
});
   

echo   $etitle = $_POST['name'];

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error);

$db=mysql_select_db('test', $conn) or die (mysql_error);


  
 
  mysql_query('INSERT INTO user(user_name) VALUES ("' . mysql_real_escape_string($etitle) . '")');

Comment: ... Use this, add code there: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22089734/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "test";

$.ajax({
    url : 'insert.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : name, // your javascript variable
    success : function(response) {

        alert(response);
    }
});
```

and in `insert.php`

```
<?php
$myVar = $POST['name'] ;

db code here
if(success)
{ 
echo "success";
}
else {
 echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: how i check my data send to insert.php file at the movment

Comment: @manjo sharma its simple in insert.php file after success you can send response back to 1st file where in success:function(response){ alert(response)} 
you can get this response .

Comment: but in success:function(response){ alert(response)} do not show anything

Comment: @manjo_sharma show me how you do it ??

Comment: //this is js
   var name = "test";
$.ajax({
  url: 'insert.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: name,
  
  success:function(response){
    }
         });

// this in insert.php

 conn.php (For database connection)

    if(isset($_REQUEST))
 
 {
   $etitle = $_GET['name'];
   
   
    $qry = mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO table(title) VALUES ($etitle)');
 }

Comment: dear use $etitle = $_POST['name'] instead of $etitle = $_GET['name'];

because above in your  $.ajax({ type : 'POST',..}); request type is POST

Comment: i have use $_POST['name'] but it also not working